# Why does using system("some.exe") in C++ method not work like the command line?

Tags: c++, windows, command-line

I am writing a program for Windows that eventually has to launch a different pre-existing .exe that sits on the same computer. It passes multiple parameters to this .exe file. I am reading the actual command and parameters and constructing the command but I also tried hard coding it with the same results. Here's the hard coded version (I picked this out of an older C program that uses the same.exe):

`system("c://IQapture//dmon2_6_IHD -p2 c://IQapture//mon_table_101_Tx8.txt 11 0 0");`

So in the original program inside `int _cdecl main(int argc, char**argv)` this use of system works. In my C++ program inside a C++ class method when I issue the command the correct program launches but it immediately puts up an error dialog stating that an error has occurred. I echo'd the system string used to launch the exe out to the console. Right after it fails, I copy and paste the same line that was echo'd and this time the exe runs without error. This is repeatable. In case it was timing related I tried adding a 10 second delay before issuing the system command but it didn't matter. Plus the original older program doesn't require a delay. This implies to me that the string is correct and the target program works. Somehow the system() invocation is different from a direct command line invocation. The program compiles and builds fine. I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Does anyone have ideas on how to make the system() invocation work like the command line invocation?

Comment: Why all those forward slashes? Also, are you sure you are running the command from the same directory?

Comment: IIRC, `system(x)` runs `cmd.exe /c x` so try putting that in at the command line.  Also check that the current directory and environment variables are the same, especially PATH.

Comment: The example is just what I copied and pasted from an older program that uses this exe that works. I have no idea why it uses two forward slashes, but it works. Nothing in my program does a 'cd' or anything similar to change directories so the directory where my .exe is should be the default.

Comment: @Harry - so just issue system("pwd"), system("Path") and system("env")? I should point out that the target system with all the required hardware is not here. I only can try things when I'm on site, so that's why I'm asking extra questions instead of just trying things.

Comment: Well, `cd` and `set` rather than `pwd` and `env`, but basically, yes.  It may be simpler to issue `system("cmd.exe")` to start a command shell and then try running the program manually from that shell, as well as checking that you're in the expected directory and that the environment is as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That really doesn't look like the kind of thing that Windows would be happy with...  Try it with backslashes instead:

```
system("c:\\IQapture\\dmon2_6_IHD -p2 c:\\IQapture\\mon_table_101_Tx8.txt 11 0 0");
```

If that still doesn't work, you quite likely have one of the following issues:

- Your current working directory is wrong;
- An environment variable is missing;
- Your program is running with the wrong user permissions;
- Your program is tying up a resource that the spawned process requires (*eg* you have not closed a file that it requires as input).

Comment: Works just as well with forward slashes. You just need one as it is not escaped like backlash

Comment: It's a bad habit to get into on Windows.  Many windows programs have lame option-processing skills which interpret a forward-slash (even in the middle of a string) to be a command-line option.  Many other programs make assumptions about directory separators when parsing path names.  So, while `cmd.exe` will happily run a program specified with unix-style directory separators, it's not necessarily a good idea to use them.

Comment: @paddy - the latter suggestions sound good. I'll have to do some more exploring, and learn more about the target program. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah it's not unusual to be writing out a file, then firing up another program to process it, but forgetting to close the file beforehand.  Good luck with your poking and prodding.

Comment: The customer ran an experiment, while my program is still running, I had them open a 2nd command prompt and cut and paste the line. It didn't work. Then they let my program quit and tried again, this time it worked. Seems like pretty strong evidence that I'm not releasing a resource. Now if I could only see what it is...

Comment: My bets would be on that filename that you pass as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of things to consider - the environment, the user running the program, the parent process and what's inherited... Take a look at the parameters to the [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) function. Chances are your system call's invocation isn't matching the command line's (though that may not be the issue, simpler things are more likely.)

I'd advise working backwards from the error to rule out simple causes such as the environment, current directory, etc. before delving into such things as creation flags and security attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You have your slashes backwards. Try:

```
system("c:/IQapture/dmon2_6_IHD -p2 c:/IQapture/mon_table_101_Tx8.txt 11 0 0");
```

You can use the backslash `\` but because that is an escape sequence starter in a string (for C/C++) that is why you use two in a row. As the compiler will convert `\\` into a single slahs in the string:

Thus:

```
system("c:\\IQapture\\dmon2_6_IHD -p2 c:\\IQapture\\mon_table_101_Tx8.txt 11 0 0");

// Is equivelent to the command line string:

> c:\IQapture\dmon2_6_IHD -p2 c:\IQapture\mon_table_101_Tx8.txt 11 0 0
```

But Windows has supported both types of slashes for longer than I can remember. So the following command line is equivalent.

```
> c:/IQapture/dmon2_6_IHD -p2 c:/IQapture/mon_table_101_Tx8.txt 11 0 0
```

Using  '/' in a string (in C/C++) does not require escaping. So you just need to use it as is:

```
system("c:/IQapture/dmon2_6_IHD -p2 c:/IQapture/mon_table_101_Tx8.txt 11 0 0");
```

Comment: The two command lines are not necessarily equivalent; it depends on how `dmon2_6_IHD.exe` parses the command line.

Comment: It's funny how everyone is concerned about the slashes even though I specifically mentioned I copied that line from source code that is known to work. Still I was wondering why the "wrong" slashes worked, so the answer is useful information in general.

Comment: @Tod: That is because `//` is treated like `/./` which is equivalent to `/`.